# Smooth scrolling to target ID on site jumps to screen upper border despite .offset().top - 50

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-apps-script

I want links to 'smooth-scroll' a the respective ID location on the same page and have a 50px distance to the upper border from this location. The smooth scrolling works just fine, and it also seems to scroll to the exact location with the upper border.

But then suddenly (a few milliseconds later) the page jumps up to the upper border (as if the '.offset().top - 50' gets overwritten by something). What happens here and how can this be fixed?

```js
$(function() {
   // Add smooth scrolling to all links
  $("a").on('click', function(event) {
    // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
    if (this.hash !== "") {
      // Prevent default anchor click behavior
      event.preventDefault();
      var hash = this.hash;
      // 800 = milliseconds it takes to scroll; - 50 = vertical location
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top - 50
      }, 800, function(){
        // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
        window.location.hash = hash;
      });
    } // End if
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="nav-link" href="#about">About</a>
 <div style="height: 2000px">testdiv before</div>
 <p style="height: 100px" id="about">target text to scroll and stop 50px above upper border</p>
 <div style="height: 2000px">testdiv after</div>
```

FYI I'm using Chrome on a 1920px viewport width, windows machine.

Comment: Seems to happen due to `window.location.hash = hash;`. https://jsfiddle.net/nd9ot0k3/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
    // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
    window.location.hash = hash;
```

This happens. Once you put the hash, if you have element#hashname somewhere the browser will scroll to it. It happens in the callback you provide here:

```
$('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top - 50
      }, 800, function(){
        // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
        window.location.hash = hash;
      });
```

The only way to go around that is to move your entire logic to the onhashchange event and trigger the animation from there. You will need to do something like:

```
function handler(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    // scroll logic here
}

window.addEventListener("hashchange", handler, true);
```

Inside the "handler" function "e" param is reference to the event object so you can get lot's of data out of it. You will be able to parse the window.location to get the exact hash you need to go to. Something like $(window.location.hash)... instead of your code.

Check here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onhashchange
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event